# Reconnect hub necessary

Tags: javascript, signalr

I have simple project in ASP.NET Web site with signalr. 
Code for start connection hub:

```
var scriptStarted = 'var myHub = $.connection.' + hubName + ';' + methodNameInitHub + '(myHub);';
$.connection.hub.error(function () {
    alert("An error occured");
});

$.connection.hub.start()
                        .done(function () {
                            eval(scriptStarted);
                            myHub.server.registerClient($.connection.hub.id, clientIdentifier);
                        })
                        .fail(function () { alert("Could not Connect!"); });
```

This method is call in "methodNameInitHub + '(myHub);"

```
function methodInitEventHub(hub) {
            if (hub) {
                hub.client.addEvent = function (eventOperationName, eventType) {
                    $("#events").append("<li>" + eventOperationName + ", " + eventType + "</li>");
                };
            }
        }
```

Code for stop connection hub:

```
$.connection.hub.stop();
```

When I load .aspx page and start hub all code execute without errors, but event from server not recieved. 
After I stop and start again hub connection events begining received in client (browser)
http://clip2net.com/s/2CP2e

Why I need to restart connection hub for begin received event from server ?
Thanks.

Comment: In first case start hub url is
/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame&connectionId=c874ed95-18f1-4eb1-b1b9-77c2c50c1d18&connectionData=[]&tid=3&frameId=1

and second case

/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame&connectionId=687838d5-c747-40f0-aaf0-2ab47423f0ff&connectionData=[{"name":"eventhub"}]&tid=5&frameId=2

Difference in parametr connectionData and frameId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having issues is because you must have at least 1 client side hub function prior to calling start otherwise you will not be subscribed to the hub.

Try doing

```
myHub.client.foo = function() {}
```

prior to start.

The reason why it works after you stop then re-start the connection is because your script binds a new client method, hence allowing you to subscribe to the hub after you've restarted the connection.

Hope this helps!